# How to get JavaFX 11 working on Eclipse 2019 (Windows 10)?

Tags: windows-10, java, eclipse

I have Java 11 (jdk-11.0.5) and this is configured on Eclipse Java Build Path for my git project. When I try to add the openjdk 11 folder as a JRE System library it says:

[Error message when adding Open JDK 11 as a JRE System Library](https://i.stack.imgur.com/igt0M.png)

The error message is: Target is not a JDK root. Java executable not found.

I am not sure how else to install Open JDK (JavaFX) 11 with Java 11 in Eclipse on Windows 10.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got it working by first adding all the lib jar files from the OpenJDK folder on the Eclipse Java Build Path by clicking "Add External JARS...". Then, adding the option:

--module-path C:/Users//Downloads/openjfx-11.0.2_windows-x64_bin-sdk/javafx-sdk-11.0.2/lib --add-modules=javafx.controls

Note: Replace the actual path "C:/..." to where you downloaded and extracted the Open JDK 11 folder and files.

to the VM arguments in the Run configuration.